# Why is this jQuery animation so SLOW on Firefox 4/5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

**EDIT by Phrogz:** This appears to be a problem with the framerate of jQuery animation when this particular complex CSS is applied. See the video at the bottom for an example of the problem.

---

I think is hard to copy and paste the whole code here. So I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markzzz/GurmR/6/) for this.

<strike>To be honest, CSS is not so important on this</strike> (I putted it for have a decent grid). I also removed many functions from my original version, in fact they aren't so important.

The only one that works is by clicking on the buttons `+ Tracks` (which call addTrack()) that adds a new track/line in the grid. Tested on Chrome, IE, and Firefox < 4 version. There isn't much problem. It's really rapid and fluid.

The problem is on Firefox 4 or 5. It's really **slow** to add the new track/line. It's fast like a turtle.

What the function done is to clone (copy with handler) an element `trackOn`, which is already written in a hidden field (tracklistOff) and add it (insertAfter) applying a fade effect. (thats means a new line in the grid).

Why this behaviour on Firefox? Too many elements to browse on the DOM I suppose. I need to get rid about this slow attitude... so what can I do?

**EDIT**

You can hear the difference about Chrome and Firefox (5, last version) on [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIETRv1Syq8) video. Try to hear/see the difference between clicking on mouse and add new line (with the effect). It's too frozen (also when I try to add more tracks quicly).

Still a problem for me, any suggestion will be appreciate :)

Comment: I ran it locally with Firefox 5 and Firebug and I'm only seeing it take 3-5 milliseconds. Can you post how you are seeing it's slow?

Comment: I'll try to make a video...if I can :)

Comment: Added the video right now! Check it :)

Answer (score 6):

1. This is not very slow for me. On my computer running Firefox 5 I can add many tracks in less than a second. What performance are you seeing? ("Fast like a turtle" is not a very quantitative measurement. :)
2. When you have trouble with JavaScript speed, *profile it*, using the Developer tools for Chrome/Safari/IE or Firebug for Firefox. Here's what I see when I run the profiler on your JSFiddle and click on the `+Track` button twice:

   [image: Profile of]

   From this we can see that most of the time is spent in some `set` function from a `mootools` library. Since I don't see this library included in your code, I'm assuming the profile is tainted by JSFiddle.
3. So, we create a [standalone test case](http://phrogz.net/tmp/markzzz.html) without the unnecessary CSS and profile that. Now we see this (for several presses of the `+Track` button):

   [image: Profile of standalone test case.]

   Almost all of your time is spent in the `clone()` function.
4. So what can you do about it? You could try pre-creating the HTML string (in JS) for a template row, and instead of using 'clone' try creating that with:

   ```
   $(templateString).hide().insertAfter(...).fadeIn(600);
   ```

Comment: Uhm...using your "standalone test case" firefox works perfectly! :O How is possible? Can you add also the CSS details on it?

Comment: It's the CSS! This is terrible frozen! Argh.... I'd like to make two video and show use! Maybe you misunderstand what I mean. Can you wait a bit of time for this? (tomorrow I hope to publish them). Just to see the button when in fact I play it : frozen! :)

Comment: For me the fade-in goes slowly on FF5, but I can still press the button many times per second and see the rows added. Perhaps your problem is just poor framerate in FF during the fade?

Comment: Yeah...maybe! But I need to get rid about this (is very bad)

Comment: Hey man! Added the video right now! Check it :) You will se the differences (the same differences are from many computers, so not only on this)

Comment: And the problems vanish without CSS! Really strange, I can't understand why of these troubles...

Comment: @markzzz Looking at your video, the problem is very clearly the framerate of the fade-in animation. Your CSS looks unnecessarily complex, which is likely causing Firefox issues when laying out the items. I have edited your question to try and make this more clear, if anyone further is going to help. If you don't get an answer, you would likely be better off just creating a new question that properly describes and shows the problem minimally.

Comment: " you would likely be better off just creating a new question that properly describes and shows the problem minimally" Yeah man, but this question show the problem... I don't know any other way to describes the problem! I'll try to convert the massive use of floated divs into tables, maybe this could help... but I don't believe much on this :(

Comment: Anyway, i've tried man, but SO people seems to dislike this kind of  topics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793645/how-can-i-reduce-the-weight-of-this-page . Funny enough...

Answer (score 1):

would it be ok if you get just the last element?
something like:

```
  $('.tracklistOff div:last-of-type')
        .clone()
        .hide()
        .insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackOn')))
        .fadeIn(600);
```

or you could `addClass(last)` to the last element to get only one

Comment: It's not a javascript problem I think. Seems that CSS made some troubles. Try to check the video... thanks for helps

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your fiddle on the following browsers and they all worked well: FireFox 5, Opera, Google Chrome, Safari & IE9.

There were no speed issues but each browser handled the fade slightly differently however everything else seemed to work fine. Not sure what the problem is here. It could be your computer speed but as you're on this site I presume it's decent.

Comment: NO, it's really terrible regard chrome :O It's like frozen for 1 second. Tried with firefox 4-5 on many computers...and it's always frozen...

Comment: I'm just reporting what my computer did, it was all fine for me but as I have found out, computers seem to have personalities and act differently all the time :P Hope you get it sorted :)

Comment: I see what you mean by 'Slower' but I think I may have an idea for the problem. I don't think that firefox is actually fading it correctly, it's taking around the same time to show them 100% but there's no fade effect. Could be the issue or may not be, either way I hope you get it fixed and good luck as I know how frustrating things like this can be :P. Good luck!